# How do split a large CSV file into small parts while maintaining headers and file extension with bash

Tags: bash, csv, split

I'm using the script below to split a large CSV file using Bash. The files are split and maintain the header is each output file.

```
csvheader=`head -1 largeFile.csv`
split -d -l500 largeFile.csv smallFile_split_
find .|grep smallFile_split_ | xargs sed -i "1s/^/$csvheader\n/"
sed -i '1d' smallFile_split_t_00
```

However, I would also like to maintain the .csv file extension on each split part.

Current output is smallFile_split_00, while I would like it to be smallFile_split_00.csv

I've tried using `split -l 500 -d .csv largeFile.csv file` but it doesn't seem to be working.

If you have any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, you generally want to use modern `$(command substitution)` syntax instead of backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename after splitting.

The `find` seems superflous; you just want

```sh
for file in smallFile_split_*; do
    case $file in
      smallFile_split_t_00)
        cat "$file" ;;
      *)
        sed "1s/^/$csvheader\n/" "$file";;
    esac >"$file.csv"
    rm "$file"
done
```

Besides being unnecessary here, `find` will also traverse any subdirectories, which clearly you don't want in this case.

Comment: Thanks for that. Working as expected.
Just for some context, I will be working with a large volume of files, so I'm looking for a more automated workflow rather than renaming manually.
Thanks again!

Comment: The code here takes care of that part, too.